# Django pass User instance to Forms when form is created

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a Django form and l would like to pass a user instance when the form is created

**First Approach**

This is where l create the form and pass the instance of the user:

```
form = QuestionForm(request.user, request.POST)
```

And inside the QuestionForm

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.data = user
    log.info(self)

Study.objects.filter(owner = self.data.id))
```

**Second Approach**
This is where l create the form and pass the request:

```
form = QuestionForm ( ..., request=request)
```

And inside the QuestionForm

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

 ref = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Study.objects.filter(owner = self.request.user.id))
```

Now l am getting an error that self is not define and as such l cannot get the user id to query the Study class

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What does this line means?
`Study.objects.filter(owner = self.request.user.id))`
It looks like it out of any methods, that's why it doesn't have any self variable to work with.

Comment: @Nick this is the complete Code  ref = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Study.objects.filter(owner = self.request.user.id))

Comment: @ErnestAppiah you should *update* your question with that code. Please always post the actual code you are running.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated the question and thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this code in field declaration section like

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    ref = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Study.objects.filter(owner=...)
```

then it will not work because it still doesn't have self variable.

You can do this in **init** method like this

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    ref = forms.ModelChoiceField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ref'].queryset = Study.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, l have modified your initial response and that solves the problem for me. I have accepted your answer and thanks a lot

Comment: @ErnestAppiah My pleasure:) But it seems that you didn't accept my answer. You should be able to mark it with a green mark.